# How to use special characters in R?

Tags: r

I have to use score.sentiment function on an amount of tweets. After, I create the score table where I can store all my companies names and relatives scores. My problem is that some companies have special characters in their names , like the accent " ' " . So, when I want to set the name of the company in my table, I have an error doing

```
wendys.scores$company = 'Wendy's';
```

because there is a problem with the second and third character. There is a way to fix this? Or I only can write 'Wendys' without the ' between the -y- and the -s- ?
Thank you in advice.

Comment: `wendys.scores$company <- 'Wendy\'s'`  (no semicolon at the end needed).

Comment: Thank you!! :D It works!!!!

Comment: Glad it helped. For more information, take a look at `?Quotes`.

Comment: Use double-quotes on the outside.  `"Wendy's"`